# PHP - split a string into an array of numerical keys

Tags: php, split

I want to split a string in PHP into a 'name' part (string)  and a 'keys' part (array of integers).

Example input:

```
 $input = "Sum(1, 5, 7)";
```

Desired output:

```
 $name = "Sum";
 $keys = [1, 5, 7];
```

I've been looking at explode, str_split preg_split, and I'm sure there are many possible implementations. What's the most elegant solution?

Comment: Euh, what about `Sum(1, Sum(1, 5, 7), 7)` ? What's the expected output ?

Comment: Is it always in the format "word" "bracket" "comma delimited numbers" "bracket"?

Comment: @Grim, Great questions. Yes I would expect it always to be "word" "bracket" "comma delimited numbers" "bracket". HamZa's example would be an invalid (illegal) input. The string is in a config file so I have control regarding unexpected inputs.

Comment: @MMacdonald Is the input `Sum(1, 5, 7)` or could there be several "parts" like `Sum(1, 5, 7) , Div(10, 5), Mul(3, 4)` ?

Comment: @HamZa - exclusively Sum(1, 5, 7) ... word, bracket, comma delimited numbers, bracket. No other variations.

Comment: @MMacdonald I think you should go with [ua6xh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1587107) solution. Explode the second part, or split it with `\s*,\s*` using `preg_split()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$input = "Sum(1, 5, 7)";

preg_match_all('#(\w+)\((.*?)\)#', $input, $m);

print_r($m);
```

Example [`Ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/wQudDF)

Comment: seems like a good start but this actually returns '1, 5, 7' as string, not as an array.

Comment: from there, just explode the string in to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$input = "Sum(1, 5, 7)";

$split1=explode('(',$input);

$name=$split1[0];
echo $name;
$newk=rtrim($split1[1],')');
echo '<br>';
$keys=explode(',',$newk);
print_r($keys)
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zy1-9np)</kbd>

Comment: Please put the code in the answer as well so the answer isn't purely a link.